# Mindbody v6 GET client/clients returns empty set from Sandbox

Tags: mindbody

I'm using Mindbody's API v6 connected to the Sandbox.
I'm trying to [retrieve clients](https://developers.mindbodyonline.com/PublicDocumentation/V6?php#get-clients) making this call:

```
https://api.mindbodyonline.com/public/v6/client/clients
```

It is returning an empty set:

```
{
  "PaginationResponse": {
    "RequestedLimit": 100,
    "RequestedOffset": 0,
    "PageSize": 0,
    "TotalResults": 0
  },
  "Clients": []
}
```

In the UI, I even created a user and registered to a class. Making this call also returns an empty set:
https://api.mindbodyonline.com/public/v6/client/clients?clientId=100015626

Has anyone been able to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turns out you need to pass a [user token](https://developers.mindbodyonline.com/PublicDocumentation/V6?php#user-tokens). Then you get results.